# Are there numbers such that A + B = 10A+B?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I was just wondering, apart from zero,are there numbers where $A+B=10A+B$ (the number AB)?

Comment: what do you mean by "(A in the tens place and B in the ones place)"? Do you want to solve $10A+B = AB$?

Comment: $0 \leq A, B \leq 9 \wedge A,B \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: He means does some like this $12\neq 1+2$ ever have $=$ instead of $\neq$

Comment: I think at least. He might mean it like this though $2\cdot 3 =2+3$

Comment: @surb yes... that's what I mean.

Comment: Your title is among the most misleading I've ever seen, given your post.

Comment: @CameronBuie I'm sorry... Can you recommend what to change?

Comment: I wish I could! Unfortunately, I'm still trying (and failing) to understand what you're asking. Sorry!

Comment: @CameronBuie What i mean is that A and B represent the digits and A+B = A*10 + B*1 ...

Comment: @CameronBuie the question has been edited... does it make more sense now?

Comment: $A+B=10A+B \iff A=10A \iff A = 0, B \in \Bbb R$

Comment: @surb pls put that as an answer...

Comment: Did  you asked which  two 2-digit numbers AB and CD sum up to a 4-digit number ABCD in the  first title of you question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Note that $\overline{AB}=10A+B$ ,where $\overline{xy}$ represents the combination of a number. E.G if $x=3$, $y=6$, $\overline{xy}=36$

Solution:
\begin{align}
A+B&=10A+B \text{Given}\\
0&=9A \tag{Subtraction Property}\\
9A&=0 \tag{Symmetric Property}\\
A&=0 \tag{Division Property}
\end{align}
When $A=0$, your number works. However, if $A=0$, it is not a 2-digit number, and thus does not meet the criteria.

Comment: FYI, this seems more like a comment...

Comment: A note on style: It's better to write something like "...and subtracting $A+B$ from both sides, we get..." rather than "Subtraction Property" - the former gives a clearer picture of what you're doing (e.g. we don't have to figure out *what* you subtracted) and flows as a sentence, whereas the latter just clutters the post, without making it any more convincing or clear (especially since "subtraction property" isn't a commonly recognized term). (Content-wise, though, this is a nice answer)

Answer (score 3):

$$A+B=10A+B$$

so

$$A=10A$$....

Answer (score 2):

By $AB$ you apparently mean $A \cdot 10 + B \cdot 1$.  Thus you are asking for $A$, $B$ such that $A+B = 10A + B$.  This is true only for $A=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow $A=0$, sure. If not, then the sum of two single digit numbers is at most $18$, so $A=1$. That becomes problematic quickly.

Answer (score 1):

$$10A + B + 10C + D = 1000A + 100 B + 10C + D$$
$$10A + B = 1000A + 100 B$$
$$9990A+99B=0$$

Not for $A, B > 0$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$A+B=10A+B⟺A=10A⟺A=0,B∈ℝ$$