# A 2-digit number is one more than 6 times the sum of its digits. If the digits are reversed, the new number is 9 less than the original number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

How to teach kids to solve this problem?

A 2-digit number is one more than 6 times the sum of its digits. If the digits are reversed, the new number is 9 less than the original number. Find the original number.

Comment: Well, how would you solve it? It's pretty much just a matter of writing out the conditions.

Comment: Do those kids know that the number $\overline{ab}=10a+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are digits? Are they used to "algebra" - using indeterminates? This looks to me like a really hard problem if they cannot do one of those (or both) - and a really easy problem if they can. (Yes, you get a $2\times 2$ system of linear equations, but it is very easy to solve by substitution.)

Comment: Looks like it is already answered in the question below.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052255/are-there-numbers-such-that-a-b-10ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$10 a + b - 1 = 6 (a + b)$$

$$10 b + a + 9 = 10 a + b$$

Solve those.

Comment: Thanks.Looks like it has already been answered as part of the question below.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052255/are-there-numbers-such-that-a-b-10ab

Answer (score 0):

If the kids are too young to be familiar with solving linear equations, one can motivate them to look for pattern.

Adding $9$ to a two-digit number reduces its units digit by $1$. This new units digit was tens digit of original. The required number is of the form $$\overline{(d-1)d}$$

where $d \in \{1,2,\ldots, 9\}$. There is only a few of them and one of them satisfies the other condition.